# Virtual Machine Specs on Google Cloud Platform for Data Science in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: scikit-learn, google-cloud-platform, data-science

I am currently running out of memory and RAM on my 2013 Macbook Pro (8gb 1600 MHz DDR3 memory, and 2 GHz Intel Core i7 processor) while running different scikit-learn (Random Search on MLPRegressor and GradientBoostingRegressor) models on a 50,000 sample data set with ~70 features, most of which are categorical. I have setup a VM on Google Cloud Platform, but have not seen much of an improvement in execution time. Here are the specs of the VM: Machine type: n1-standard-8 (8 vCPUs, 30 GB memory), Source image: ubuntu-1604-xenial-v20180126. I'm wondering if anyone has any recommendations on tweaking vm specs for learning data science. I'm not looking to add any GPUs due to cost. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As the volume and nature of the data you plan to process is known to you, simply experimenting with different machines on Google Cloud Platform is the best way to choose the most effective option.
General information on subject is to be found in the "[Google Cloud Platform for Data Scientists](https://cloud.google.com/data-science/)" document. 
In case you may still consider this option, "[Graphics Processing Unit (GPU)](https://cloud.google.com/gpu/)" provides an overview of this component in the context of data science.